# Formatting Resharper backing fields for properties in C#

Tags: c#, resharper

Is there a way to control where Resharper puts its backing fields?  currently it tries to put them at the top of the class.   Id like them to go right above the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not yet.