# What's the standard naming convention for a property's backing field?

Tags: properties, naming-conventions, typescript, backing-field

#### Background

I'm wanting to follow the most commonly-practised naming conventions for TypeScript. I've noticed that the official website shows [code examples featuring Pascal-case for types and modules and camel-case for just about everything else](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Tutorial/).

#### Example

I'm currently implementing a property that encapsulates a backing value:

```
class SomeClass {
    get status() {
        return statusBackingField;
    }
    set status(newValue: Status) {
        statusBackingField = newValue;
        //Do other work here
    }

    statusBackingField: Status;
}
```

#### Problem

The name of the property is `status`. In C#, I would normally name the property `Status` and the backing value `status`. Since the convention is to use camel-case for properties, this doesn't work. I'm not sure which convention I should use for consistency with other TypeScript code in general.

#### Question

Other languages, such as C# and Java, seem to have official or de facto standard conventions. Is there any such authoritative or de facto standard convention for naming backing fields in TypeScript?

#### Notes

For the close-voters: please note that I'm not looking for opinions. I'm looking for objective information as requested in the summarised question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's safe to say at this stage that there is no standard.

If someone can point me to an authoritative standard or evidence of a de-facto standard, then I may consider accepting their answer instead.

Comment: The typescript handbook suggests `_leadingUnderscore`. Read more here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors.

Answer (score 3):

There is [no code convention standard](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1742) for TypeScript. Since it is a superset of JavaScript, following JavaScript code conventions would probably be the correct approach. In such a case you would use an underscore-prefixed property `_status`. Idiomatically, this also matches the compiler’s use of an underscore-prefixed `_this` for compiled arrow functions and underscored-prefixed `_super` for superclasses.

Comment: +1 A good principle in variable naming is to avoid solely relying on case to differentiate between variables - which is why many C# programmers use the `_name / Name` convention, rather than `Name / name`.

Answer (score 2):

In C# as well as TypeScript we use `private _status`. In C# the property will be `Status`. In TypeScript as you mentioned it is `status`

Comment: In your second sentence, did you mean "property"?

Comment: I'm looking for either an authoritative source of a recommendation, such as Microsoft, or some sort of evidence that this convention is the de-facto standard.

Comment: @Sam this is the convention set the resharper : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755809/resharper-7-1-to-property-with-backing-field-moving-fields-out-of-place The generated backing field is `private type _name` you can try it for yourself.

Comment: @Sam the coding conventions mentions what you said `status` instead of `_status` but microsoft isn't consistent with it. e.g. the EDMX designer will generate `_Status` : https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/master/Imports/Newtonsoft.Json/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Tests/FileSystemEntityModel.Designer.cs?source=c#L366-L370

Comment: Those examples look like C# code. I'm looking for evidence of a standard naming convention used in TypeScript code.

Comment: @Sam the TypeScript team announced pretty early on that they wanted to see what the community did before recommending this kind of thing. Although the MS C# standard states that you shouldn't use an `_` to prefix private fields, it is becoming increasingly accepted that it is better to do that than rely on prefixing a variable with `this.` when there is a conflict. I think it is likely that the underscore convention will become the accepted standard as Basarat says - but don't expect MS to dictate it for you at this stage.

Comment: But what do I do with completly public variables with no special get/set function? Since I can't add an underscore, I would have a mix of members with and without `_`.

Comment: a this right moment I'm using a mix of conventions between Java and C#: the property concept for instance is pretty similar to C#, then I use the property with Capital letters; for interfaces I'm using another C# convention, that is with the Capital I before the name (I was influenced by angular.d.ts); eventually I hate the underscore for fields, then none of them before or among the letters (as a Java convention specifies).